# Why am I getting a warning about hook_civicrm when Civi's cron runs?

Tags: drupal, cron, hooks

On Drupal 7.73 with CiviCRM 5.29.1. Every time the CiviCRM cron runs, I get the following warnings in the Drupal watchdog log. Each is a separate entry.

hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )

hook_civicrm_entity_supported_info should be updated to pass an array of parameter names to CRM_Utils_Hook::invoke(). Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )

Any suggestions for how to fix this would be most welcome :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Wow - this totally worked for me ! No more clogged log file. Thank you Eileen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the civicrm_entity module installed. There's an open pull request for this at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/pull/238

If you're able to test out that patch and comment there on that PR it might get merged faster.

Comment: Thank you Demerit. I don't know how to install patches, so I will just wait for the module update whenever it comes. I appreciate your taking the time to let me know.